# About stack exchange problem solving website

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation is 61. I can't upload photo in problem solving website. When will I be able to upload a photo in this website?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126

Comment: Are you talking about the Problem Solving Strategies chat room?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 100 rep to upload photos. For now you can upload the photo to your favourite image hosting site, e.g. [Imgur](https://imgur.com/), and then post the link to it in the chat room.

As mentioned in a comment, the details of chat room privileges are described [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).