# Could we link the "Image equation to TeX" question from TeX SE somewhere?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, mathjax, formatting

It has been discussed before that [one should not post images of text or formulas](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/). However, many users still do – probably because they consider typing all this text too much work, which to some degree is understandable.

I (probably) had the same problem and then found this question on TeX SE: [Image equation to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863/) which shows some useful ways to easily convert screenshots to LaTeX. I personally have used the proposed tools to edit some of the questions here.

So could we link this somewhere in order for users to have a simpler way to convert their screenshots to text/equations (which hopefully would decrease the amount of textual screenshots)? Possibly below the "Please use MathJax for equations in questions." in the sidebar when asking a question.

[image]

Would this be in the interest of this community?

Comment: To some extent this feels like guiding users to tools that are not necessarily complete best practices. But it's certainly something we can advertise e.g. on a community ad.

Comment: One further quibble: the tex.se thread seems to be a direct recommendation for mathpix. (I.e.: the other answers do not offer sufficient information on the systems they recommend to give any idea whether the system is useful or not.) And mathpix is not free.

Comment: It's amusing to me that this question includes an example of posting an image with no working link to it's source.