# Questions being responded to negatively

Tags: discussion, support, scope, questions, specific-question

I know that there are some similar questions like this one, but I have a genuine concern. For example, the question *[A puzzling simple question on thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710807/)* or [another](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710509/) I had deleted.

Apparently this community does not like being asked questions on genuine problems and questions which someone may be stuck on. I see mostly concept and theory questions being asked, but I sometimes I am unable to solve tricky sums and need help. And they are not homework sums as many assume (even moderators).

This is by no means a complaint, just a guy seeking how he can get his questions answered online.

Comment: What, exactly, is the input you're looking for here? If you think that your questions should be on-topic because they are not *actually* homework, then that's not what our policy is about - it's about the *content* of the question, not whether it was actually assigned to you as homework or not.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for the reply. My point is that my questions on which I am stuck even after spending like an hour, are left unanswered. On top of that they are unnecessarily downvoted, and negative comments are given.

Comment: The thermodynamics Question was closed without giving any reason also. It’s just that I’m not quite happy, because I have more doubts which are problems / questions, rather than concepts.

Comment: I understand that you are unhappy, but as far as I can see, your questions are downvoted and closed because they are *off-topic* under our homework-and-exercises policy. These closures do not occur "without giving any reason" - you should see a close banner at the top that explains the reason why the question is closed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind will look into it and try to see what I can do. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Regarding performing sums, we generally won't help with this unless there's a technique that needs explaining (e.g. a tricky integration technique or a problem with more advanced math that's learned as part of a process of learning some theory, like tensor calculus).  Normally worked out answers to homework-type questions will be voted down by the community, as we're only supposed to explain a concept.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Right, I didn't know that, will work upon it. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You posted a question after working for an *hour*?   I usually give it at least a week.

Answer (score 6):

I simply do not understand how you can believe that a question taken from a physics olympiad is not a homework question.  It may not be a homework *to you* but it is or will likely be homework for someone.  Remember that the purpose of the site is to provide answers that are useful to visitors beyond  the OP, not just for the OP.

As to your other question, you did not even bother typesetting it.  In all fairness, it would not have been useful to do so as it is also clearly a homework question.  Cut-and-paste of images is also highly frowned upon, as discussed in [this thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/36194).

I suggest that, if you are stuck on a questions *for days or weeks* (not for merely an hour!), or if you have exhausted multiple textbooks without answers, it is likely to be a conceptual question, which is what this site is devoted to (as you correctly identify).

Answer (score 0):

The tag we use to represent homework question is called homework-and-exercises. We always assume exercise-related question is homework. And Olympiad questions are also called exercises. hence it is homework. Furthermore, any kind of question (not talking about conceptual questions) in books or in any exam is considered to be an exercise. Read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/315444)

Comment: *We always assume exercise-related question is homework.* We do put this tag on such questions, but we **don't** assume it's all homework; we actually don't care at all where the question came from or the motivations of the person asking the question.