# Does math in my questions need to be in the form of MathJax?

Tags: discussion, questions, mathjax, formatting

I asked a question recently. With the question I included a picture of the question with my best handwriting. But received very harsh criticism from two users who insisted that the question be in MathJax form. I have made the promise that I will learn it later. However, does this mean that without use of MathJax, my question will never be answered?

Comment: Please see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/

Comment: You’re not respecting the rules of the site, which expects math to be in MathJax. If you link to handwritten equations, most readers will simply ignore your question and not help you, although some might. You should not be surprised if your question gets placed on hold, or deleted entirely.

Comment: There is a good tutorial at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. However, some of the inline MathJax is not getting displayed, which is an embarrassment.

Comment: why not learn it now?

Comment: @bguner I apologize if my brashness offended you on the physics SE

Comment: related: [How to deal with users that just won't use MathJax?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10284/84967).

Comment: I'll say that I tend to _downvote_ questions with pictures of text frequently. I have an unusual display (high-resolution but small), and text on my display looks rather small. Pictures skew that by forcing the text they contain to be really big. I'm sure that several other people have similar issues. However, I'd probably not VtC such posts unless there's a _really, really huge_ amount of text or the author is a perpetual offender who argues that s/he doesn't care that some people can't read the content easily.

Comment: Here is a [link to bguner's question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443245/prove-the-second-covariant-derivative-of-fracyvdk-is-equal-to-the-riem). The equations have now been converted to MathJax.

Comment: @N.Steinle thank you for being the bigger person here, Perry’s about my behavior too. I have actually solved the question I posted yesterday. I was irrational and spiteful because I was frustrated. I mean I tried to solve that one problems for 2 days with no luck and no idea of the trick I was meant to use. Again I am very sorry for my behavior and hope you can find it in your heart to forgive me =)

Answer (score 5):

> However, does this mean that without use of MathJax, my question will never be answered?

The short answer is no, it doesn't mean that.

But there's more going on here than just MathJax. From what you described, it sounds like your question actually had a much more severe problem, which is that you posted images of something that could be typed out. That's a big no-no here. We expect anything that can be typed should be typed, not posted as an image, because images are not searchable, not always archivable, not accessible to screen readers, may not be readable for everyone, take up significantly more storage space and bandwidth, and so on - this has been discussed at length [elsewhere on this meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/discouraging-screenshots-of-questions-at-least-the-textual-part). Rightly or wrongly, posting an image of text (or math) makes you look kind of lazy, and that makes a lot of people pretty reluctant to help you out - we are much more motivated to help answer questions where the poster has done their research, not only on the question itself, but also on how to properly ask it here.

Sometimes your question will still be answered even if you post images of text or don't use MathJax for the math, but it probably will take you longer to get an answer, and you're less likely to get a really good one. Using the proper formatting increases your chances of getting a good answer quickly.

Now, as a new member to the site, we understand that you might not know MathJax already, so people can be a little bit more lenient, when it's your first post, if you use images for equations or type them out without using MathJax. In those cases, you'll probably get a comment asking you to use MathJax for the math, and someone may be nice enough to do the edit for you to give you an example of how it works. But that's only for brand new site members. Once you've been told about MathJax, or you've been around for a little while and seen it in use, you should be using it yourself. It's not particularly hard to [learn the basics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and as long as you're making the effort (and learning as you go), people will probably be willing to fix up minor mistakes for you.

Comment: The original version of [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443245/prove-the-second-covariant-derivative-of-fracyvdk-is-equal-to-the-riem) only had the equations in an image, it didn't have non-equation text in the image.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, I hadn't looked at the original question, and the way the meta question was asked, it made it sound as if more than just the equations was in an image. In any case I think most of my answer still applies, although it doesn't _look_ quite as bad to have just the equations in pictures, compared to chunks of text.